# Using Jquery in Sharepoint to load a header and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I am trying to load a Header and Footer, but ran into a load time issue where it is loading really slow on Sharepoint, tested with WAMP and works fine. 
I am using

```
$(function(){
   $("#headerFile").load("header.html");
   $("#footerFile").load("footer.html");
});
```

and have tried using document.ready as well.
I also want the header and footer to load before the content  but if the faster load time makes that less noticeable that is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the code below:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#contentBox").hide(); //hide content 
    $("#headerFile").load("header.html",function(){
        $("#footerFile").load("footer.html",function(){
            //show sharepoint content
            $("#contentBox").show();//show content
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Or we can create loader and hide the loader after the SharePoint content loaded.

**Refer to**: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, main issues is the load time on Sharepoint still taking forever for loading header and footer. Think this is a Sharepoint thing since i tried it on WAMP and it was fine.